# What are the most crucial categories of content to organize into an internal developer portal in a large company?

Tags: programming-practices, development-process, documentation, coding-standards, training

I have been tasked with organizing all of the company's internal content currently spread around sharepoint, a markdown reference manual and confluence into a single cohesive and usable portal in confluence. I want the home page to be the "dev center" and for it to be where we point new devs and where everyone goes for reference and to see what is going on at the company. Here are some general categories I imagine might be important:

1. news... what's going on in the company, promotions, new hires, project updates
2. best practices... coding standards, solutions to common problems, etc...
3. on-boarding... docs describing how to set up a dev environment on your workstation
4. company culture... org chart, roles and responsibilities, the functions of different groups, processes
5. training... courses coming up, recommended and required training
6. events... events coming up, slides and materials from previous events

Anything else you think is important to include? My goal is to have this portal be something devs actually want to look at multiple times per day for help doing their jobs.

Expected user base is around 500 devs, testers, ops, etc... across over a dozen teams. Both .Net and Java are in use in this Enterprise. The page will be in Confluence, so I believe we can let everyone contribute in some way, or should we lock it down and appoint content managers? Good point about analytics. I will include that in my proposal.

Thanks for the input!!

Comment: Ask the developers what content they use and how they use it. Ask them what other content they would like to see.

Comment: Do you have any sort of internal analytics for your current site? Do any of these sites exist already for other employees you could use (ie HR benefits info, news, etc)?

Comment: How big (aprox.) is the expected user base for that portal? How many devs, how many teams? And do you have someone for managing the content regularly?

Answer (score 2):

A few other things to include:

1. Calendar - What are the key dates coming up for the dev team?  Are there milestones to be aware?  Are there code freezes or other things that may be worth noting here.
2. Links to various other systems - Bug tracking, incident management, feature tracking and other stuff may be useful to have as links here so that a developer can easily click to them from this page as new hires and others may not always be aware of all the systems.  Links to the project sites could also be included in here.
3. The company culture could be split into a few pieces: 1) Corporate values that may be stated in the side as a short message, 2) Links to HR policies for things like time off, performance reviews, etc. 3) A team's "who's who" that may be different than the formal org chart and could include cell numbers to contact people if there is a problem after hours.
4. The best practices could be split into what is done within your company and what other resources are out there.  For example, your company may have its own naming convention for variables that is different than what some best practices may say.  Similarly, the dev process you use may be different.  Just consider the idea of having what is within the company in one part of the page and recommendations from others as another part of the page.

It may be worth having some "Quote of the day" or other daily updated feature that could be useful as a way to entice people to go to the portal regularly.